# jQuery toggleClass not changing css

Tags: jquery, css

I am using jQuery to make a dropdown menu. Next to each object to open a dropdown there is a triangle, like this:

[image]
 I have two CSS classes, `.caret` and `.u-caret`. Class `caret` looks like a triangle pointing down, and class `u-caret` looks like one pointing up. I want the classes to switch when I click on the object.

HTML:

```
<span id="learn">Open Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></span>
```

CSS:

```
.caret {
       border-top:5px solid black;
       border-left:5px solid transparent;
       border-right:5px solid transparent;
}
.u-caret{
       border-bottom:5px solid black;
       border-left:5px solid transparent;
       border-right:5px solid transparent;
}
```

JS:

```
 $('#learn').click(function(){
       $('#learn-dropdown').toggle().css('z-index','200');
       $('#affiliate-content-dropdown').css('z-index','100').slideUp();
       $("#snippet-dropdown").css('z-index','100').slideUp();
       $('#stories-dropdown').css('z-index','100').slideUp();
       $(this).closest('.caret').toggleClass('caret').toggleClass('u-caret');
    });
```

Comment: `closest()` doesn't work that way; it works outward/upward, not inward. Also, notice that once you've toggled off `caret`, `closest('.caret')` can't possibly match the next time you click the element, so you'll never toggle it back on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.closest looks upwards in the hierarchy what you want is find:

```
$('#learn').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.caret').toggleClass('caret').toggleClass('u-caret');
});
```

This also won't work after the first time because the toggle will remove the class .caret. What you want is an unchanging class:

```
<span id="learn">Open Dropdown <span class="arrow caret"></span></span>
```

Then you find the .arrow element:

```
$('#learn').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.arrow').toggleClass('caret').toggleClass('u-caret');
});
```

Comment: The first code snippet should be $(this).find('.caret, .u-caret').toggleClass.... As far as the second one, it looks good but you can also combine classes in toggle method by a space. For example $(this).find('.arrow').toggleClass('caret u-caret')

Answer (score 2):

As noted in my comment, you can't just search for `.caret`. Once it's toggled off, `find('.caret')` no longer works. Search for either class, toggle all that you find:

```js
$('#learn').click(function() {
  $('#learn-dropdown').toggle().css('z-index', '200');
  $('#affiliate-content-dropdown').css('z-index', '100').slideUp();
  $("#snippet-dropdown").css('z-index', '100').slideUp();
  $('#stories-dropdown').css('z-index', '100').slideUp();
  $(this).find('.caret, .u-caret').toggleClass('caret').toggleClass('u-caret');
});
```

```css
.caret {
  border-top: 5px solid black;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
}
.u-caret {
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="learn">Open Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></span>
```